# C# - Determine if application Spans multiple Monitors

Tags: c#, window

I am wondering if there is a way in C# to determine if a running applications window is using a single monitor or spanning over multiple monitors?

I know I can get monitor count for available monitors but not sure how to determine if a current program is spanning over multiple monitors. Any suggestions?

Comment: [Somewhat related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670507/how-a-multi-monitor-application-can-detect-a-missing-monitor), maybe you can look at the application window size and see if the horizontal is bigger than half the horizontal screen resolution?

Comment: Building on tnw, you could look at the `left` value of application and add it to the `width` to compare that.

Comment: Only way I can think of is enumerating the monitors and checking x,y,width,height in relation.

Comment: This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681738/how-do-i-determine-if-a-window-is-off-screen/4681861#4681861 may help

Comment: @Qwerty01 i also thought of that, this would be somehow tricky, because the application could be very small in size, but it could be placed exctly between the two screens (if there are only two screens).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Screen.AllScreens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find where your users' screens are, and do some math based on the window position, perhaps using [Rectangle.Intersects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.intersectswith.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! What I ended up doing was getting the Rect bounds of the application window. Then doing:     System.Windows.Forms.Screen[] screens = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens;

            
            
            for (int index = 0; index < screens.Length; index++)
            {
                if(screens[index].Bounds.IntersectsWith(windowBounds))
                {